# Excel-Conditional Formatting- Highlight the difference that is greater than

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

[image]

I am trying to figure out the proper way to enter the formula.

I am looking at highlighting the difference that is greater than 20000000

`=$H-$G>20000000`?

any suggestions

Comment: I think you want `$H2-$G2>20000000` and apply to your range?  Do you have an issue as it is? Do you get an error/unexpected outcome?

Comment: @BruceWayne - Agreed - the CF formula should refer to the first cell(s) in the "applies to" range

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't really do it over a range like that.  I believe you want this as your formula:

```
=$H2-$G2>20000000
```

and an applied to range of say

```
=$H$2:$G$1000
```

to do this for all cells from row 2 to 1000.